# Multiple references to KnockoutJS script breaks the standard behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

For example,

1. I have the page where KO has been already registered and there is a viewmodel with observable property "someProperty";
2. I check that the "someProperty" is observable property by ko.isObservable(viewmodel.someProperty) - it returns 'true';
3. I do the ajax call to get some html markup where KO is registered too;
4. Now If you check the ko.isObservable(viewmodel.someProperty) it will return false;

Also all KO extensions which has been added manually will be lost. It looks like bug (or feature) in jQuery (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10066).

```
var viewModel = new function() {
            var self = this;
            this.serverData = {
                Controller: ko.observable(null),
                Enabled: ko.observable(false),
                Id: ko.observable(null),
                ParentId: ko.observable(null),
                Title: ko.observable(null),
                MaterialId: ko.observable(null),
                Alias: ko.observable(null)
            };
            this.treeData = {
                tree: ko.observable(null),
                node: ko.observable(null)
            };
            this.submit = submit;
            this.cancel = cancel;
            this.openMaterials = menuOptions.openMaterials;
}

// ...
var data = ko.utils.createUnobservable(viewModel.serverData);
// ...

(function(ko) {
    ko.utils = ko.utils || {};

    ko.utils.createUnobservable = function(observable) {
        var unobservable = {};
        (function() {
            for (var propertyName in observable) {
                var observableProperty = observable[propertyName];
                if (ko.isObservable(observableProperty) /* always 'false' after ajax */) {
                    unobservable[propertyName] = observableProperty();
                }
            }
        })();

        return unobservable;
    };

})(ko = ko || {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fix this by saving a copy of the `ko` global variable before you include the loaded ajax, and then restoring it afterwards.

```
var savedKo = window.ko;
.... // do the ajax thing
window.ko = savedKo;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's clear, I've already thought about it, but it's something like workaround. But anyway, is it normal behaviour for referenced script library ?

Comment: I think it's normal behavior.